# use sequence object for multiple tables to ensure querability on join

Tags: oracle, database-design

I am using Oracle. I have two tables:

Cat (cat_ID, cat_name, cat_age, cat_strength)

Dog (dog_ID, dog_name, dog_age)

Sometimes I need to get all pets into one query result. I was thinking of creating an animal_seq sequence that can be used by both Cat and Dog tables so that they never have duplicate IDs across tables and then when joined can be easily searched/queried whatever.

Is this bad practice? If so, why? Are there better ways to design the tables (eg just one Animal table, or multiple inheritence). Personally, I try to avoid inheritence due to the performance issues of joins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a single sequence is totally acceptable and safe.  Oracle ensures multiple reads to a sequence always returns a unique value so you shouldn't have any problems with duplicate keys.

If the the schema between CAT and DOG is truly unique and an additional animal entity will also be unique, I would keep separate tables.  If you are going to maintain the same information about cats, dogs, monkeys, etc., I would recommend putting them into a single ANIMAL table.  You'll have to give more information about the application/database for us to know what to recommend.

Comment: Cats have a foreign key to a scratch pole table (I am making all of this up btw, substituting names to protect the innocent). Dogs have a foreign key to a dog kennel table. Owners (of pets) can buy kennels or scratch poles. etc etc..

Comment: Hmm...given this, you might consider having an ANIMAL table, PRODUCT table, and an ANIMAL_PRODUCT_XREF table.  The ANIMAL_PRODUCT_XREF would be a cross-reference table joining ANIMAL_ID to PRODUCT_ID.  This way you can have multiple products available to multiple animals.

Answer (score 1):

With your current design what if you wanted to record birds or rabits or any other animal ?You would have to create tables for each type.

I would say use KISS(Keep it simply stupid) principle and have one table and join to another table called ANIMAL_TYPE( animal_type_id,Animal_type_name) that way you can make the sure ids are not duplicate and you can tend should you want to record other animal types.

Comment: the problem is that there will be lots of null values as dogs don't have strength attributes (for example). Though, I am still considering that option.

Comment: surely dogs have strength :). while you may have lots of null values your design would be future proofed. How are you doing your joins?

Comment: @BobTurbo: Keep in mind that Oracle only uses 1 byte to store a null, and trailing nulls in a row do not require any storage.  So while there may be some logical concerns about sparse tables, such as the tables are so large they are annoying to use, the physical issues aren't nearly as bad as many people assume.

Comment: yep null values aren't a major concern. My concern is with the fact that cats and dogs have foriegn keys to other entities and if you didn't separate them into cats and dogs, you would not be able to link the other entities directly to the cats and dogs. I didn't include this information in my question though as I didn't have time to think up a way to express things via cats and dogs.

Comment: In my opinion, the problem with nulls isn't as much a space issue as it is a design issue.  A truly normalized design minimizes the use of NULLs.  When table has a ton of NULL columns, it signals the clear definition of the entity is weak.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a base table, `animal`. Then you have two sub classes `cat` and `dog`. Such a design will help you when you add information such as "owner" of that animal, or "animal observation" or whatever the purpose of your application is.

```
table animal(
   animal_id 
  ,animal_type <-- Discriminator column with for example C for cat, D for dog 
  ,name
  ,age
  ,primary key(animal_id)
)

table cat(
   animal_id
  ,cat_strength
  ,primary key(animal_id)
  ,foreign key(animal_id) references animal(animal_id)
)

table dog(
   animal_id
  ,dog specific attributes here
  ,primary key(animal_id)
  ,foreign key(animal_id) references animal(animal_id)
)
```

As you can see, I've moved up common attributes to the base table `animal`, while keeping the specific attributes for the subclasses in the sub class tables.

Comment: The problem I have with this is that every single insert will require two inserts, and every single query will require millions of joins. While this is how it would be done if these were objects, I am not sure if oop works too well in a database.

Comment: The performance penalty is minimal and only noticable for web-scale-awesome-sauce projects. Go for a clean and expressive model in which the database can enforce all or most of the integrity constraints and worry about performance later. You will find that neither joins nor nr of tables have any noticable impact on any specific performance problem.